# How to remove uppercase text from start of excerpt?

Tags: php, regex

Assuming text like the following...

```
NEW YORK -- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eget ante pellentesque, tempus augue non, volutpat augue. Donec accumsan eros eget felis molestie maximus non quis nulla. Nullam ante tellus, vestibulum at rutrum quis, rutrum eget magna. Nulla nec nulla blandit, venenatis enim non, accumsan justo. Nunc aliquam libero vitae dui fermentum malesuada. In vel interdum leo, a elementum risus.
```

... How, in PHP, would I remove the part "`NEW YORK --`"?

That is:

- any uppercase word or words,  including whether they contain a symbol or space (eg. `CANNES`, `FLORIDA`, `BURTON-ON-TRENT`)
- only where they *start* the supplied text
- where the word/s is/are suffixed by "`-- Lorem`" (space, double-dash, space), followed by alphabetical sentences.

I want to be left with only the portion after "`--`".

Comment: why not use `explode`?

Comment: search for the position of "--" with strrpos and remove everything in front of i

Comment: Try `(?<=--\s).*`[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9p2hEV/1)

Comment: Why not enclose the first part in a non capturing group, use a positive lookahead for `-- Lorem` and then start capturing? Try `(?:^[A-Z\s]*--\s)(?=Lorem)(.*)` [here](https://regex101.com/r/iUyCw1/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'NEW YORK -- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eget ante pellentesque, tempus augue non, volutpat augue. Donec accumsan eros eget felis molestie maximus non quis nulla. Nullam ante tellus, vestibulum at rutrum quis, rutrum eget magna. Nulla nec nulla blandit, venenatis enim non, accumsan justo. Nunc aliquam libero vitae dui fermentum malesuada. In vel interdum leo, a elementum risus.';

$res = preg_replace('/^[-A-Z\h]*?-- /', '', $string);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eget ante pellentesque, tempus augue non, volutpat augue. Donec accumsan eros eget felis molestie maximus non quis nulla. Nullam ante tellus, vestibulum at rutrum quis, rutrum eget magna. Nulla nec nulla blandit, venenatis enim non, accumsan justo. Nunc aliquam libero vitae dui fermentum malesuada. In vel interdum leo, a elementum risus.
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               : beginning of string
  [-A-Z\h]*?    : dash or any uppercase or horizontal space, 0 or more times, not greedy
  --            : 2 dashes
```